# Can not instantiate an object inside a PHP heredoc in common.php (and/or $this is out of object context!!)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

My Web app should allow the user to input hex values for label-color, background-color and font-color.I need to be able to update the background color, label color and font color depending on the hex values that the user inputs which are saved in a MySQL table.  My goal is to pull the hex color values from the database at the beginning of the common.php (which is my css) and assign them to three color variables ($clabel, $cbackground and $cfont) and use them inside my css so that the all the color changes are in one place. But I am running into some problems and the root of all the problem is that $this is not in object context inside common.php  - - - I was wondering what an I do to achieve the same result going forward. (I also want to mention here that I tried including a class and instantiating an object of that class inside common.php. It does not work and my whole webpage loses all its formatting defined in commom.php)

***Scenario 1:***

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css");
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("shiprequ_sr", $con);

$userid = $this->user->id;

$resultUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users Where Id=$userid");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultUser,MYSQL_NUM))
  {
    $templateId =$row[15];  
  }

$resultTemplates = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM templates Where Id=$templateId"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultTemplates,MYSQL_NUM))
  {
            $clabel = '#'.$row[14];
    $cbackground = '#'.$row[13];    
    $cfont = '#'.$row[16];

 } 
mysql_close($con); 

?>

<style type='text/css'>
.text4                          
{
color: <?=$clabel?>;// font and bkg colors are referred to likewise  
}
```

The above code only works when 
    $userid = $this->user->id; 
is replaced with a specific user id for example 
    $userid = 101;
For some reason $this is not accessible in common.php.

**Scenario:2**

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css");

include('C:/sr/application/models/getdata.php');
$clabel = getLabelColor(); 
$cbackground = getBkgColor(); 
$cfont = getFontColor(); 
 ?>

<style type='text/css'>
.text4                          
{
color: <?=$clabel?>;// font and bkg colors are referred to likewise  
}
</style>
```

getdata.php looks like following:

```
function getLabelColor() { 


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("shiprequ_sr", $con);

$userid = $this->user->id;

$resultUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users Where Id=$userid");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultUser,MYSQL_NUM))
  {
    $templateId =$row[15];  
  }

$resultTemplates = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM templates Where Id=$templateId"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultTemplates,MYSQL_NUM))
  {

    $clabel = '#'.$row[14];

  } 
 mysql_close($con); 

return $clabel;
}

//getFontColor() and getBkgColor() defined likewise
```

This code messes up the whole webpage as if the css does not eist.

When I use the same code from layout.phtml (as a test):

```
<!--In layout.phtml-->
<?php
include('C:/sr/application/models/getdata.php');
echo $clabel = getLabelColor(); //purple 51:0:153
echo $cbackground = getBkgColor(); //Light blue 102:102:204
echo $cfont = getFontColor();
?>
```

I get the following error :

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\sr\application\models\getdata.php on line 14
```

I am wondering why $this is not in object context as it is used in my code or how can put it in object context?

Comment: It looks. to me, as if you are not using Zend Framework correctly. You should work through the [quick start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) to learn how to use it.

Comment: Your scripts should not be sending a text/css header AND outputting `<style>` tags. Should the output be a stylesheet or a HTML page?

Comment: @Tim The output should be a html page. Someone advised me to do it and I assumed that when I use <?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ------?> I have to use <style type = 'text/css'> ----- </style>

Comment: @ vascowhite I am not very adept with Zend so I dont think I used any of their functionality in this module. I am just manually opening the database and the reading the values and assigning them to variables. However other modules do use Zend and I would go through the quick start soon.

Comment: But the main problem is that '$this is not in object context' when used inside common.php and in getdata.php. I am wondering why its not in object context and when is it in object context.

Comment: If the output is HTML then remove the header line. Where should the user ID come from? I.e. what is it that populates $this->user?

Answer (score 0):

As you have determined, the problem is with the code line:

```
$userid = $this->user->id;
```

The reason that there is a problem with this code is that `$this` is a special variable that is only valid within the context of a method of a class.

common.php is a procedural file and does not have a class defined and hence `$this` is not within an object, which is why you get the error message.

Assuming you're using Zend_Auth, you could change that line to:

```
$userid = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->id;
```

However, in the context of a Zend Framework application, common.php is not the type of code you'd expect to see. Rather, you should move the functionality to a set of controllers, models and view scripts.

Comment: $userid = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->id does not work and it messes up the formatting of the whole page just like $userid = $this->user->id; It is as if no common.php exists.

Comment: That implies that you are not using Zend_Auth then.

Comment: Zend_Auth is used at the controller level - -  may be i would have to implement a css controller.

Comment: You will need to retrieve the user id from the session.

Answer (score -1):

You can use $this only in class, for example

```
class TestClass {
    private $name = "Name";
    public function echoName() {
        echo $this->name; // use $this only inside class
    }
}
```

If you have object $user as global variable, then you need to add

```
global $user;
```

as first line of your function getLabelColor() and then use it like that:

```
$userid = $user->id;
```

Read more about [Classes and Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) in php